# Enable button if a checkbox in loop is checked Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

i'm relatively new on Angular 5 i have a button like this:

```
          <button *ngIf="type!='invoices' && this.action==='edit'" disabled (click)="genera(fields.termini)" class="ml-16 mat-raised-button mat-accent" mat-raised-button="" disabled color="primary">Genera fattura</button>
```

i need to add another condition to my component.ts that enable this button only when one of the checkbox in a loop is selected. Here is my loop:

```
   genera(model) 
   {
    for (let scadenza of this.model.partial_payments) 
    {
      if (scadenza.fattura === true && scadenza.payed != '') 
      {
        alert('Funziona');
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple things going on here. First off: in your html you are setting `disabled` twice, which your editor should be complaining about. Second, you need a backing field to bind your `disabled` status to. Then you need to bind disabled like this: `[disabled]="myBackingField"`. I would bind this to a getter in my component or model if it were me. Here's an example of how you could create a getter that encapsulates this logic:

```
get anyPartialHasFattura(): boolean {
  for (let scadenza of this.model.partial_payments) {
    if (scadenza.fattura === true) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

And here's a stripped down version of your button that binds `disabled` to this new field:

```
<button [disabled]="anyPartialHasFattura">Genera fattura</button>
```

Finally, [here's a quick stackblitz I put together to show this in action](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-example-for-stack-overflow?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts). Try clicking one of those checkboxes and see what happens to disabled state on the button.

One final note on why `[disabled]="someBoolean"` works. The only actual valid way to represent `disabled` as `false` in HTML is via the omission of the `disabled` attribute altogether. So why does this work? You should read [this section of the Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#a-new-mental-model) on template syntax. I'll include some especially relevant quotes:

> You'll get to that peculiar bracket notation in a moment. Looking
>   beyond it, your intuition suggests that you're binding to the button's
>   `disabled` attribute and setting it to the current value of the
>   component's `isUnchanged` property.
>
> Your intuition is incorrect! Your everyday HTML mental model is
>   misleading. In fact, once you start data binding, you are no longer
>   working with HTML *attributes*. You aren't setting attributes. You are
>   setting the *properties* of DOM elements, components, and directives.

...

> The `disabled` attribute is another peculiar example. A button's
>   `disabled` property is `false` by default so the button is enabled. When
>   you add the `disabled` attribute, its presence alone initializes the
>   button's `disabled` property to `true` so the button is disabled.
>
> Adding and removing the disabled *attribute* disables and enables the
>   button. The value of the *attribute* is irrelevant, which is why you
>   cannot enable a button by writing `<button disabled="false">Still Disabled</button>`.
>
> Setting the button's `disabled` *property* (say, with an Angular binding)
>   disables or enables the button. The value of the *property* matters.
>
> The HTML attribute and the DOM property are not the same thing, even
>   when they have the same name.

Comment: Thank you very much for explanation and great help. Something in my code is wrong because i got this error: ERROR TypeError: "_a is undefined"
getwebpack-internal:///../../../../../src/app/main/content/pages/edit-form/edit-form.component.ts:275:64

Comment: What is at `edit-form.component.ts` on line 275? Is your code being minified and you are missing a null/undefined check but getting a bogus error due to minification? You could do a null check before `for (let scadenza of this.model.partial_payments) `. Something like `if (this.model === null) return false;`. Or check for `this.model.partial_payments`. It's hard to say without seeing your code and being able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: #275            this.model = model;

Comment: On your class do you have a field defined that is called `model`? If I were you, I would try to reproduce the error on StackBlitz and ask a new question on how to fix that error.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using disabled use `[attr.disabled]`

```
<button *ngIf="type!='invoices' && this.action==='edit'" [attr.disabled]=" buttonDisabled == true" (click)="genera(fields.termini)" class="ml-16 mat-raised-button mat-accent" mat-raised-button="" disabled color="primary">Genera fattura</button>
```